# Gremlin bulk load csv date formate

Tags: bulk-load, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I am trying to upload data in to the AWS neptune, but getting error because of date format

sample format of csv:
~id, ~from, ~to, ~label, date:Date
e1, v1, v2, created, 2019-11-04

can some one help me on this?

Comment: Could you please share the error message  you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test today using a CSV as follows

```
~id,~from,~to,~label,date:Date
e1,3,4,testedge,2019-11-19
```

and it worked fine. This is after the load:

```
gremlin> g.E('e1')
==>e[e1][3-testedge->4]
gremlin> g.E('e1').valueMap()
==>{date=Tue Nov 19 00:00:00 UTC 2019}
```

Perhaps curl the loader endpoint for your cluster adding `?errors=true&details=true` to the curl URL

Cheers,
Kelvin